# 301 redirect to 404 page or set status code to 404 and stay on page?

Tags: 301-redirect, 404

I have a number of pages on my website that only administrators can access and access to these pages is given if a querystring value if found and correctly set. For example:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/show-daily-statistics?key=abc
```

The above link will show the content of the page but anything else such as the below will not:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/show-daily-statistics
```

Now I was thinking about what to do if search engines and/or non-admin users somehow land on these hidden pages.

I can of course either change the status code of the page to 404 or else 301 redirect to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/404-error
```

What's the best solution in respect to Google and SEO?

Comment: I would consider implementing actual authentication instead, if the information you're trying to hide has any importance at all. Apart from that, a 301 redirect semantically indicates that the content has moved which is not the case here and therefore it is an inappropriate response.

Answer (score 12):

### The correct code would be 401 Not Authorized

As per the HTTP specifications

#### 10.4.2 401 Unauthorized

> The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a
> WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge
> applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the
> request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If
> the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401
> response indicates that authorization has been refused for those
> credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the
> prior response, and the user agent has already attempted
> authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the
> entity that was given in the response, since that entity might include
> relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is
> explained in "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access
> Authentication" [43].

or alternatively

#### 10.4.4 403 Forbidden

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
> Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If
> the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public
> why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason
> for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make
> this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not
> Found) can be used instead.

Both of these are semantically more correct than `404`. The resource exists so `404` isnt' correct. `401` should be correct, but you aren't requiring authentication. Security by obscurity isn't security. `403` is also correct as the request is understood, the resource exists it is just refuses to service the request. `404` is appropriate if you don't want to reveal why `403` is happening.

In any case `301` redirects are **not** appropriate, the resource hasn't moved.

Comment: But the page requires no authentication, at least not the old-fashioned browser username/password dialog we get on some pages such as http://blink.ucsd.edu/_images/technology-tab/ICO-proxy-winfire3.jpg I want users and search engines to believe that this page doesn't exist at all rather than being a page that requires a username and password combination.

Comment: Google does not index and removes pages returning 401/403 status messages, a [similar question was asked awhile back](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29275/what-does-google-do-with-indexed-pages-returning-403) alternatively you could always [use a simple noindex](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) and [block using robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Comment: I considered adding these pages to the robots.txt file but someone with malicious intentions such as a competitor will then easily find out about these pages. I prefer to keep them "secret" by of course not linking to them and generate a 401 or 404 if someone gets to them by pure luck.

Comment: @WPRookie82 About protecting page by keeping it secret - you're doing it wrong.

Comment: security by obscurity is not security at all

Comment: The use of 401 for authentication methods other than HTTP Basic or Digest auth (or other RFC2617-compatible auth schemes) [has been discussed here before](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24443/should-i-return-a-http-401-status-code-on-an-html-based-login-form); my opinion at the time, which I still stand by, is that it *may* work in practice, but it's not really valid according to the HTTP spec, and that in any case, 403 or even 404 would be preferable.

Comment: I agree with other comments that 401 Unauthorized is inappropriate according to the HTTP spec.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a page for administrators, with or without the "key" parameter, the pages can't and should not be indexed. Therefore the webpage for non-admin can send 404 status code, and you can leave the same URL intact. Do not redirect, since you tell Google that the page has moved, but then to a page that doesn't exist.

This is how Google does it as well. See what happens when you go to a dummy page: 
http://www.google.com/analytics/asdsas

Comment: One small correction to my above post, `http://www.example.com/404-error` exists, it's a sort of global 404 page of the whole website so I wound not be redirecting to a non-exiting page.

Comment: @WPRookie82: As far as anyone *except* you and your webserver is concerned, there's no difference between a non-existent page and an existing page that returns a 404 response.

Answer (score 1):

The semantically correct HTTP response code for this situation would be [**403 Forbidden**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.4):

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
> Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.
> If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make
> public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the
> reason for the refusal in the entity.  If the server does not wish to
> make this information available to the client, the status code 404
> (Not Found) can be used instead.

(Although the definition of the 403 response says that "authorization will not help", IMO this should be understood as [referring specifically to HTTP Basic / Digest authentication](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24443/should-i-return-a-http-401-status-code-on-an-html-based-login-form/24452#24452), for which the status code *401 Unauthorized* should be used instead.  Since you're *not* using either of those authentication methods, 403 is the appropriate status code in your case.)

---

However, using a 403 status code reveals (or at least strongly implies) the fact that there *is* a page with that URL, even though the server is refusing to deliver it.  As this is something that you may wish to conceal from potential intruders, the HTTP/1.1 standard explicitly allows the [**404 Not Found**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.5) status code to be returned instead (*emphasis* mine):

> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No
> indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or
> permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server
> knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old
> resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.
> *This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to
> reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other
> response is applicable.*

Of course, to make such concealment effective at all, the 404 error page you return needs to appear identical to what you return for *actual* non-existent pages.  Otherwise, it will only fool the dumbest and most casual attackers.  (If your goal is just to keep the pages out of Google's index, a 403 response will do that just as well.)

---

What about the other possible responses suggested in your question and the other answers?

As I noted earlier, [I do not believe that a 401 response is appropriate here.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24443/should-i-return-a-http-401-status-code-on-an-html-based-login-form/24452#24452)  It *may* work in practice, insofar as most  browsers and search engines will treat any malformed or unrecognized 4*xx* series response code as if it were a 404, but it's still not valid according to the HTTP spec, and there's no practical reason to prefer it over 403 or 404.

As for using a 301 (or 302) redirect to a separate "404 error" page, that's an *awful* practice spread by sloppy mod_rewrite tutorials, and has absolutely no redeeming features as compared to returning a 404 response directly:

- It's confusing to visitors, as the URL they were *trying* to visit gets replaced by the URL of the error page.  Thus, they see a message saying they've reached a non-existent page, but no easily visible indication of *what* the page they were trying to visit was, and so cannot easily attempt any recovery strategies like fixing any obvious typos in the URL, or copy-and-pasting it into Google or the Wayback Machine.
- It may confuse search engines, [especially if your 404 page is disallowed in robots.txt](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24569/why-do-google-search-results-include-pages-disallowed-in-robots-txt), or if it incorrectly returns a 200 OK response instead of a real 404 status code (["soft 404"](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/08/farewell-to-soft-404s.html)), potentially causing your 404 page to appear in search results for random search terms.
- It causes (a small amount of) extra load on your servers, increases the response time to visitors and potentially slows down search engines crawling your site, as every request for a non-existent (or concealed) page now involves an extra HTTP round-trip.
- It has no SEO benefit, as any "link juice" from pages redirected to a 404 page is lost anyway.

(Of course, the one situation where you *do* want to use a 301 redirect instead of a 404 response is when the page actually *has* moved, and you can redirect the visitor to its correct location.  But that's not the case discussed here.)

---

Finally, I would like to echo the sentiment, expressed in many comments here, that merely "hiding" your admin pages like this is *not* an adequate substitute for [proper password-based authentication](http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-stickies-167/program-basic-secure-login-system-using-php-mysql-891201.html).  That said, *if* you already have a secure authentication system set up, hiding the pages may be useful as an extra layer, albeit a fairly weak one, in a [defense in depth](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)) approach.

Comment: I finally decided to opt for what you suggested in the second part. Whoever lands on the page without a valid key will see my regular 404 page and I am of course returning status code 404 in the process.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `noindex,nofollow,noarchive` tag in the head of the pages you want to get out of search.

I've found that the `noarchive` tag tends to get things out of search pretty damn quick, whereas the `noindex` may stop it getting into search, but if its already out there, then you need to flush it out of search results.

As for the admin access question, the other guys here have already given some advice on security that I'd recommend checking out.